# Error in latex command \def ... "Undefined control sequence"

Tags: latex

I have the following Latex code, which defines the \fmiso command with the command \def, but it seems that this definition does not work.
What is wrong?

```
...

\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage{apalike}
\usepackage{SCITEPRESS}    
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\subfigtopskip=0pt
\subfigcapskip=0pt
\subfigbottomskip=0pt

\def\fmiso{\mbox{FMI-S$_O$}\xspace}
\def\fmis{\mbox{FMI-S}\xspace}


\begin{document}

...

which is the model implemented in \fmiso

...
```

Then I am getting the error:

```
Undefined control sequence... which is the model implemented in \fmiso
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another case of TeX's error messages being cryptic. I'm getting this full error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\fmiso ->\mbox {FMI-S$_O$}\xspace 

l.28 wich is the model impletented in \fmiso
```

So (at least for me, in this minimal example), `\fmiso` gets expanded just fine. The "undefined control sequence" is always the *last* one on the line printed, in this case `\xspace`.

This is a bit clearer if we add another command inside the `\fmiso` definition, which is then shifted to the next line:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\fmiso ->\mbox {FMI-S$_O$}\xspace 
                                 \TeX
```

I could resolve it simply by adding:

```
\usepackage{xspace}
```

---

Aside: in LaTeX, it's [better](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/658/2837) to use LaTeX to define new commands:

```
\newcommand{\fmiso}{\mbox{FMI-S$_O$}\xspace}
```